# ggplot2: Add two number of observation in each stacked graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-text

I have a df as it follows:

```
fruit <- data.frame(Sample=1:100, 
        Fruit=c(rep("Apple", 10), rep("Strawberry", 25), rep("Grape", 20), 
              rep("Watermelon", 15), rep("Lime", 11), rep("Blueberry", 10), 
              rep("Plum", 9)), 
        Color=c(rep("Red", 30), rep("Green", 45), 
                rep("Blue", 25)), 
        Ripe=c(rep(c(T, F), 50)))+

fruit$Fruit <- factor(fruit$Fruit, unique(fruit$Fruit))+
fruit$Color <- factor(fruit$Color, unique(fruit$Color))
```

Then, I've plotted the bar graph:

```
foo <- aggregate(Sample ~ Color, data = fruit, FUN = length)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(fruit, aes(Color, fill = Color, alpha = Ripe)) +
geom_bar(color = "black") +
geom_text(data = foo, aes(label = Sample, y = Sample), alpha = "1", vjust = -1)
scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0.6)) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NA)))
```

With the command above I was able to create the following bar-graph:

[image]

So...I was able to put the total number of observations for each Color above each bar...but I'm wonder how can I put the total n of observation for TRUE in each color bar. In this case would be two n observation for each bar, with one above the bar as the total n of each Color (as you can already see), and above the TRUE bar the TRUE n observation for that particular Color...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a little more aggregation:

```
foo2 <- aggregate(Ripe ~ Color, data = fruit, FUN = sum)

foo2$label <- foo2$Ripe
foo$label <- foo$Sample
foo_stack <- do.call(rbind, list(foo[,c("Color", "label")], foo2[,c("Color","label")]))
```

And then change your `geom_text()` to:

```
geom_text(data = foo_stack, aes(label = label, y = label), alpha = "1", vjust = -1)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do all your aggregation in `data.table` in one step like:

```
library(data.table)
foo_stack <- as.data.table(fruit)    
foo_stack[,.(labels = c(sum(Ripe == TRUE), length(Ripe))) , by = Color]
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Good one @Mike H.

Comment: @guidebortoli, no problem! I also updated my answer to show a solution that does all the aggregation in one line using `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

Could do it e.g. this way, aggregating by both `Ripe` and `Color` at first to get both positions

```
fruit <- data.frame(Sample=1:100, 
                    Fruit=c(rep("Apple", 10), rep("Strawberry", 25), rep("Grape", 20), 
                            rep("Watermelon", 15), rep("Lime", 11), rep("Blueberry", 10), 
                            rep("Plum", 9)), 
                    Color=c(rep("Red", 30), rep("Green", 45), 
                            rep("Blue", 25)), 
                    Ripe=c(rep(c(T, F), 50))) 

fruit$Fruit <- factor(fruit$Fruit, unique(fruit$Fruit))
fruit$Color <- factor(fruit$Color, unique(fruit$Color))

foo <- aggregate(Sample ~ Color + Ripe, data = fruit, FUN = length)
labs <- data.frame(Sample = c(foo[foo$Ripe == TRUE, "Sample"], aggregate(Sample ~ Color, data = foo2, FUN = sum)$Sample))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = fruit, aes(Color, fill = Color, alpha = Ripe), color = "black") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0.6)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NA))) +
  geom_text(data = labs, aes(label = Sample, x = rep(1:3, 2), y = Sample), alpha = "1", vjust = -1, color = "black")
```

[image]